# Parameters of Normal vs. Transversal cylindrical projections

Tags: coordinate-system

I need to parameterize a cylinder that cuts the ellipsoid. One time in normal case   (eg. like Mercator) and one time in transversal case (eg. like Transversal mercator).
So, in normal case the cut cylinder is papameterized using the geographic location of the cutting circles, but in transversal case the cylinder is parameterized by setting a scalefactor. And I wonder why?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please try to add more information/details to you question; it's rather unclear at present. Use **[edit]**.

Answer (score 3):

For Mercator, the cylinder is oriented along the North-South axes. There is thus a single orientation. If you want to adjust the deformation, you can play on the radius of the cylinder (hence affecting the scale). This projection works best near the equator, because this is where it fits the most to the ellipsoid. Using the position of the cut circle instead of the scale factor gives you an immediate insight of the location where it is exact.

For transverse Mercator, the axis of the cylinder is oriented perpendicularly to the North-South axis (and you have an infinity of possible orientation). Therefore you first need to specify the orientation of the cylinder. This projection works best near one meridian, because this is where it fits the most to the ellipsoid (yet not as well as the normal cylinder, because of the flattening). But if you look at the cut circles in the secant case, you'll see that they do not correspond with meridians. So you cannot "locate" them like the parallels in the normal case. Therefore it is better to use the central meridian and a scale factor.

Comment: Just what i thought the Q might be, and what the A was, but was too lazy (and uncertain) to do it myself :-)